Building npm package with Webpack (module has no exports)
I try to build an NPM module with Webpack. When I build the module, it generates a file in the  .dist folder, but it seems that the created module has no export, I don't understand why.
Here is my JS source file:
./src/index.js
const helloNpm = () => {
  return "hello NPM"
}

export { helloNpm } ;

here is my Webpack configuration:
./webpack;config.mjs
import path from 'path';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";
const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;



export default (env) => {


  // Prepare the config variable
  let config = {

    // Set compilation mode
    mode: 'production',

    devtool: false,

    target: 'web',


    // Default entry point is main
    entry: {
      index: ['./src/index.js'],
    },


    // The location of the build folder
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: '[name].js',
      library: {
        name: "my-library",
        type: "umd",
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        
      },
      globalObject: 'this',
      publicPath: '/',
      clean: true,
    },


    // Aliasses
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        Static: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/static/"),
        Js: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/js/"),
      }
    },


    // CSS, images and HTML loaders
    module: {
      rules: [

        // CSS loader
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          exclude: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },

        // CSS lazy loader
        {
          test: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
          use: [
            { loader: "style-loader", options: { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' } },
            { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } }
          ],
        },


        // HTML loader
        {
          test: /src(\/|\\)js(\/|\\).+(\/|\\)[A-Za-z]+\.html$/i,
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: { sources: false },
        },

      ],
    },

    // Plugins (copy, html css minifiers)
    plugins: [

      // Minify CSS
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ]
  }

  //console.log(config.entry);
  return config;
};

//export default config;

Here is the output code generated by Webpack in the dist folder:
./dist/index.js
! function(e, t) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = t() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("beautiful-css", [], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports["beautiful-css"] = t() : e["beautiful-css"] = t()
}(this, (() => (() => {
    "use strict";
    var e = {
            d: (t, o) => {
                for (var r in o) e.o(o, r) && !e.o(t, r) && Object.defineProperty(t, r, {
                    enumerable: !0,
                    get: o[r]
                })
            },
            o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
            r: e => {
                "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                    value: "Module"
                }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                })
            }
        },
        t = {};
    e.r(t), e.d(t, {
        helloNpm: () => o
    });
    const o = () => "hello NPM";
    return t
})()));

